# How to find descriptions for exit codes in Linux?

Tags: exit-status, documentation

I'm looking for textual explanation of Linux exit codes (like 124 for `timeout`, 130 for `SIGINT` received, etc).

I thought `errno` from `moreutils` does this but it seems it is for looking for error numbers?   What is the difference anyway?

```
$ errno 124 && errno 130
EMEDIUMTYPE 124 Wrong medium type
EOWNERDEAD 130 Owner died
```

As you can see, these explanations are wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is ill-posed, because programmers can decide for themselves which exit status they return in case of certain errors. This is why you usually find a `RETURN CODES` or `EXIT STATUS` section at the end of man-pages for linux programs where this is described _for that program_. There are some attempts to standardize, but unless you mention the program for which you are looking to understand the exit codes, it is impossible to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Status codes 128 and above are not even reported by the process itself. They are generated by the kernel when processes are killed by signals, and are (128 + SigNum), where the signal numbers are given from `kill -l`. Values from 124 to 127 are returned by shells on behalf of processes they couldn't even start (e.g. by failure to fork or to find a command to exec). The timeout command apes this behaviour: in fact, `man timeout` says it will SigKill the process if it ignores the TERM signal, and return (128+9) instead of 124. Or, the process can catch the signal and exit with its own status.